# How to get the correct XPath for ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I tried for the past 2 hours using an xPath scraper, inspecting, googling and still can't figure this out for the life of me.

I'm trying to scrape the interest rates on this table but it's not pulling through ->

**Website**
https://www.fhlbboston.com/fhlbank-boston/rates#/long-term

**Formula (incorrect)**

```
importxml("https://www.fhlbboston.com/fhlbank-boston/rates#/long-term","//table",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

import formulae of google sheets does not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can always check this by disabling JS for a given site and usually only what is left can be imported. in your case:

[image]

the workaround would be to find alternative URL that hosts your desired dataset